# WS_TRANS = {ord(_wschar) : ' ' for _wschar in string.whitespace} AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'whitespace'

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to create a module using setuptools. I installed setuptools and wrote a small piece of code as TestFunction.py:

```
  def function(test):
        print(test);
    function("hello World")
```

and created a setup.py file with the below instruction:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
      name='TestFunction.py',
      version='1.0',
      description='this is a python distribution',
      py_module=['TestFunction'],)
```

Now i am running python3 setup.py sdist and getting the below error. My os is  ubuntu 18. Much appreciated.

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
  File "/home/jeet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import distutils.core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 18, in <module>
    from distutils.fancy_getopt import FancyGetopt, translate_longopt
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/fancy_getopt.py", line 373, in <module>
    WS_TRANS = {ord(_wschar) : ' ' for _wschar in string.whitespace}
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'whitespace'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a file `string.py` that isn't a module from the standard library but your own module or script. Rename it so it doesn't overshadow the standard module; don't forget to remove `string.pyc` file; for python 3.6 it's in `__pycache__` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code because you have an indentation formatting error. Rest of your code works fine.

copy and try this:

test_module.py

```
def function1(test):
  print(test);
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='test_module.py',
    version='1.0',
    description='this is a python distribution',
    py_module=['test_module'],)
```

usage:

```
python setup.py install
```

use your function:

```
from test_module import function1
function1("hello stackoverflow")
```

output:
hello stackoverflow